# Make delegate variable both a subclass and conform to protocol

Tags: swift

I have this delegate that conforms to `SomeProtocol`

```
weak var delegate:SomeProtocol?
```

Now I want this delegate to be a subclass of `SomeClass`.

How can I do that in one declaration?

Do I have to define a new subclass that both inherits from `SomeClass` and conforms to `SomeProtocol`?

Comment: Note that there are several similar questions already, for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29881621/make-property-of-type-and-also-conform-to-protocol-in-swift

Comment: We should mark this as duplicate or delete it then

Answer (score 0):

In Swift you can make your class inherit from another class and conform to several protocols.

Here's the syntax

```
protocol CanRun { }
class Animal { }

class Cat: Animal, CanRun { }
```

Comment: Is there a way in one line to declare a variable of one class type and inherits from one protocol?

Comment: No, there is no such a thing in Swift

Answer (score 0):

A variable can have just one class type or conform many protocols, in your case you can create another protocol that `SomeClass` conform, let say `SecondProtocol` and specify that your `delegate` conform both `SomeProtocol` and `SecondProtocol`:

```
weak var delegate: protocol<SomeProtocol, SecondProtocol>
```

or do what you said about the new subclass.

Comment: Is there a way in one line to declare a variable of one class type and inherits from one protocol?

Comment: No, there's no way to do things like *var delegate:SomeClass,protocol<SomeProtocol>* if it's what you want.